# Closing a window using ViewModel first MVVM and Stylet

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, stylet

I'm using a MVVM ViewModel first approach with Stylet and I'm struggling to close a window from it's ViewModel.

In the [Stylet Wiki](https://github.com/canton7/Stylet/wiki/Screens-and-Conductors) it states that I can use:

```
Screen.RequestClose
```

I have the following code:

```
public class MdExportViewModel : Screen
{
    public MdExportViewModel()
        {
            if(canExport == true)
            {
                this.RequestClose();
            }
        }
}
```

When I try to call the 'RequestClose' I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to close ViewModel
> Drain.ViewModels.Windows.MdExportViewModel as it must have a conductor
> as a parent (note that windows and dialogs automatically have such a
> parent)'

I've tried adding the `Conductor<T>` as follows:

```
public class MdExportViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>
```

But I get the same error. I didn't really understand how a conductor should be used in this instance. I assumed my origional attempt would work since `note that windows and dialogs automatically have such a parent`.

What am I doing wrong here? Other answers to similar questions use complicated workarounds, but I'd like to use a Stylet method to keep things consistent and simple.

**EDIT:**

The window is opened in another viewmodel as follows:

```
    public void ExportMD()
    {

        MdExportViewModel MdExportViewModel = new(networkMain, DesignCriteriaViewModel)
        {
            Parent = this
        };
       
        this.windowManager.ShowWindow(MdExportViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: How did you show that window? I'm guessing you didn't use `IWindowManager.ShowWindow(new MdExportViewModel())` or similar?

Comment: I've added an edit to show how the window is opened

Comment: Why are you doing `Parent = this` there? That should be getting overwritten straight away by the `WindowManager`

Comment: Aha, the problem is that you're trying to close the `MdExporyViewModel` from its constructor. The framework hasn't yet had a chance to set up its parent properly at that point. Override the `OnInitialActivate` and put your close logic in there -- that's called as soon as the window is shown. Or, you know, change your logic so that you're not showing a window then immediately closing it again.

Comment: I see, I think I'm going about this the wrong way then. If I add a button to the window which triggers the 'this.RequestClose();' it works just fine. But if I call it in 'OnInitialActivate()' it seem to work, but then 'ShowWindow' fails as it's trying to open something that's already closed. I'm trying to open a window, that shows progress, then closes if no issue has been identified.

Comment: All sorted thanks. Placing the close command in 'OnViewLoaded()' does exactly what I need.